# "Failed to start cryptography" after resizing of root partition

Tags: boot, encryption, luks

I had a basic setup with a LUKS encoded small partition mounting on system boot subject to typing in password. I extended the root Ext4 partition from Windows. This didn't affect encrypted partition whatsover.

After that I'm no longer getting to password form, getting a message "failed to start cryptography" and "failed dependencies for encrypted folders".

All in all the GUI doesn't start.

Any ideas what I can fix to get encryption running properly?

Comment: What tool did you use to extend the ext4 partition? Did you resize the file system afterwards to have it fill the newly-added space? The gui does not start - does that mean that you have command line access? Can you use `udisksctl` to unlock the partition?

Comment: Thank you for comment. I did it via Windows Paragon tool. I did have command line access. The solution for me was to turn off Lusk partition by deleting relevant lines in fstab, cryptotab. Then I managed to get gui started and miraculously adding back partition to fstab  restored original setup but this time everything is working.